# Шифруется файл и создается дубликат

Tags: шифрование, вирусы, восстановление

Здравствуйте,подскажите,пожалуйста,как быть.
Вирус поразил файлы,сам файл не доступен и создается его дубликат  с расширением ***.gs*** имя его такое **имя *файла+какое то цифровое значение+kim@korea*** .Может кто сталкивался с подобным,как расшифровать подобное,пытался через восстанавливающие утилиты от касперского,доктора вэб,также просто восстанавливающие утилиты,результата нет.Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Создавайте пост на форуме Dr. Web (http://forum.drweb.com/index.php?showforum=35) или http://virusinfo.info/. Предварительно изучите правила и приложите всю требующуюся информацию, это сильно ускорит процесс. Вам постараются помочь. Из своего опыта могу сказать что помогают, хотя наверное все зависит от от блокировщика который вам попался.

Comment: В данном случае не одна неделя потребуется, я прикидываю...

Comment: Так и есть. В моем случаи это заняло недели 3. Если у вас нет близких знакомых которые очень хороши в реверс-инженеринге, то быстро и бесплатно вам вряд-ли кто-то поможет.

Comment: Я сам тот самый человек, который расшифровку для них пишет. И я говорю - не одна неделя.

Comment: @Владимир-Мартьянов Прошу прошения. Я думаю это будет еще в рамках этого вопроса и расширит его информативность. Скажите а каковы шансы не расшифровать?

Comment: Вероятность всегда от 0 до 1.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Хорошо, по вашему опыту каков процент неудач?